# Implementing production settings in Django

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm having trouble understanding the switchover from local to production settings for deploying Django projects. I'm using an Ubuntu virtual machine (VM) if it matters.

I understand how to configure my settings. I understand best practices for creating settings files (base.py, local.py, production.py, blah, blah). I know that in local development DEBUG=True, in production DEBUG=False, blah, blah.

But how do I implement this switchover in deployment? Do I get rid of the local.py? Do I create some kind of logic so that my VM only reads base.py and production.py?

What's the best approach?

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid multiple settings files and instead use [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to handle your changing settings as environment variables. Checkout the [12-factor-app](https://12factor.net)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo for the reply. Your recommendation is indeed tempting. However I have requirements and apps for things that I do not want in production (testing apps, documentation generators, etc.). Until I figure out a cleaner solution, for now I will keep my settings.local.py out of version control, and always deploy from a production ready git repo. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the best approach but what I do works...

At the foot of my settings.py, I have:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    pass
```

I keep all my local development settings in local_settings.py which overide any production settings. I also make sure not to upload my local_settings.py file!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to check in your settings py which environment is used at the moment. 
To do this you can set an environment variable on your system that would have diffrent values on your development environment and the production environment.

you can set these environment variables by

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

and add the following line in the file:

```
DEBUG="true"
```

(to make this changes available you will have to log out and log back in into your system)

in the production environment you would then set DEBUG="false". 
then you can do this in your settings.py:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'true') != 'false'
```

and then you can set every setting that would be different depending on the environment that is used like this:

```
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
else:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
```

(the setting above uses the local django server to serve staticfiles if it is in the development environment, and amazon s3 with boto if in the production environment (which is defined in the custom_storages module)

This way you can push your updates and always the right settings should  be picked up depending on the environment.